# React.NET .NET Core 3.1 Not passing props into component

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am using MVC ASP.NET Core 3.1 and React.NET and I am getting this issue.

When I render my component, the component renders, but the props are always null.  It is almost as if the Html.React render method isn't properly passing the values over, please help!

I'm only going to add relevent code to the react (my startup.cs has more settings)

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

            services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName).AddChakraCore();
            services.AddReact();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
            app.UseReact(config =>
            {
                // If you want to use server-side rendering of React components,
                // add all the necessary JavaScript files here. This includes
                // your components as well as all of their dependencies.
                // See http://reactjs.net/ for more information. Example:
                config
                    .AddScript("~/scripts/react_common/login.jsx");

                 config.SetLoadBabel(true);
            });
}
```

index.cshtml (or any view, just trying to use this HTML extension helper)

```
           @Html.React("Login", new
           {
             Test = "Test"
           }, serverOnly: true)
```

login.jsx

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.Test}</div>
    }
```

No matter what I do, it will never display "Test" for example.  I need to know why it isn't passing the values into the props. I am starting to lose my mind over this problem, it worked just fine before I started migrating to .NET Core.

More details (Nuget Packages)

React.Asp.Net(5.1.2)
React.AspNet.Middleware(5.1.2)

Please help.

Comment: Did you call `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()` somewhere?

Comment: No, I didn't think I needed to because this is server side rendering.  But I tried anyway and it still didn't work.

Comment: Making more progress, props are being converted into pascalCase for some reason.  How can I enable it to simply keep the existing case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default JSON serializer contract resolver is set to automatically convert it into camelCase (React).  You have to over-ride this behavior if you want it to maintain the supplied case - in the Configure method in startup.cs:

```
app.UseReact(...
app.UseStaticFiles();

//Ensure to place this after the UseRact statement above
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration.JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

Hopefully this helps someone else from going crazy