# Pass properties in a component React by a Razor page, value are not showen

Tags: reactjs, razor-pages, react-props

i have a project ASP.NET CORE MVC and i want to pass an object of the Model in a component react. My purpose is to pass a list of object but doesn't find simple properties of the object passed for test. The properties seems to be undefined, how con i pass it correctly??

[EDIT] Now is not undefined anymore but nothing is showen. And i can't use console.log to check the value of props cause seems to not show simple message too.

```
class App extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('hi')
    }
    
    render() {
        
        const { Property1, Property2 } = this.props;
       
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Property1: {Property1}</p>
                <p>Property2: {Property2}</p>
                <div className="box">Sono un box</div>
            </div>

            );
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.React("App",new { Property1 = "value1", Property2 = "value2" })
```

The file has only this string of code cause i want only a component to be insert, but as you can see in the inspector it's not a component called App but a div with an id, is it correct?

[EDIT]
this is how the page looks in the inspector:
[image: inspector:]

Comment: I solved the problem following this other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013968/react-net-net-core-3-1-not-passing-props-into-component

Answer (score 0):

The props are passed to the component constructor and are available as `this.props` inside `render()`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { Property1, Property2 } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Property1: {Property1}</p>
                <p>Property2: {Property2}</p>
                <div className="box">Sono un box</div>
            </div>

            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't give me Undefined but doesn't print anythings...why?

Comment: And most important, why if i put a console.log(this.props) for example, in the console is not showed anythings??also with console.log(5)....